# how to do a looping to retrieve streaming image?

Tags: c#, aforge

how can i get all the streaming jpeg to create an avi?

```
Bitmap img = eventArgs.Frame;
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    //img.SetPixel(i, i, Color.Red);
    writer.AddFrame(img);
}
writer.Close();
```

i got this example from AForge, http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/5fedbbbe-6d28-5f69-35a2-9d7119544a2d.htm
but when i test it, it create a video file with 1 same frame from beginning to the end of the video.

how can i execute the writer.AddFrame(img); to create video file with new frame everytime?

EDIT:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;

using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;

using AForge.Video;
using AForge.Video.VFW;
using AForge.Video.DirectShow;

namespace VidRec
{
    public partial class LiveRecording : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        AVIWriter writer = new AVIWriter("MSVC");   //video with compression

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            //camera source
            string streamingSource = "http://e888.example.com:81/snapshot.cgi";

            // create new AVI file and open it
            writer.Open("c:\\video.avi", 640, 480);

            //IPcam streaming source to be recorded
            JPEGStream JPEGSource = new JPEGStream(streamingSource);
            //MJPEGStream JPEGSource = new MJPEGStream(streamingSource);
            //login name and password
            JPEGSource.Login = "login";
            JPEGSource.Password = "password";
            //set NewFrame event handler
            JPEGSource.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(video_NewFrame);

            //start streaming the image files
            JPEGSource.Start();
    }

    private void video_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs) //event handler for NewFrame
    {
        //get frame
        Bitmap image = eventArgs.Frame;
        //add the image as a new frame of video file
        writer.AddFrame(image);

    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        writer.Close();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your example you will see that they modify the image in each loop. You don't, so you have the same frame from beginning to the end.

Comment: how can i modify the loop so i get a different frame?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the next image in to your img for each iteration of the loop.

you cold load them up in an array and just loop over that inside your for loop.

---

edit after comment

say you have 10 images names 1.jpg to 10.jpg

you cold make an array like this.

```
        Image[] imageAry = new Image[10];

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            imageAry[i] = Image.FromFile(string.Format("{0}.jpg", i + 1))
        }
```

then you wold use your imageAry array inside your for loop and iterate over each picture.

Comment: how if i dont know what is the image file name i'am receiving as i receive it from IP cam?

Comment: Ok, i know the image file i receive but the image file name is named using timestamp. yyyymmddhhmmss format.

Answer (score 0):

To Test an example just make little change and uncomment 4th line like:

```
Bitmap img = eventArgs.Frame;
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    JPEGStream JPEGSource = new JPEGStream(streamingSource);
    img = (bitmap)JPEGSource;
    // if JPEGSource is stream not image then use below like instead of above line
    // img = Image.FromStream(JPEGSource);
    writer.AddFrame(img);
}
writer.Close();
```

if above doesn't work and you are saving this stream to any folder with name as timestamp.jpeg then you can use code below:

```
using System.IO;
```

Now:

```
Bitmap img = eventArgs.Frame;
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    // JPEGStream JPEGSource = new JPEGStream(streamingSource);
    // save it to folder like d:\images\
    // if you are saving images to folder using any other program 
    // then this might not be needed
    string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"d:\images\");
    foreach(string f in filePaths)
    {
        img = Image.FromFile(f);
        writer.AddFrame(img);
    }
}
writer.Close();
```

Comment: thanks for commenting but that not what i am asking. what you provide i already test it and i dont want to create a video file with the same frame and without the red line. That y i comment the 4th line.

Comment: this line update frame and every frame is different, So you need to provide new image every time. Do you have array of images or images saved in any folder to create video from?

Comment: images is received from IP camera.

Comment: Do you receive it by your program using some function or it saves in some folder for you to scan?

Comment: i'am using the JPEGStream from AForge to receive the image file from camera(live streaming). `JPEGStream JPEGSource = new JPEGStream(streamingSource);`

Comment: if JPEGSource is image of type JPEG or it's video stream?

Comment: I have added changes you could try and reply

Comment: i edit my code above for what i have done so far. Please take a look. i also tested your code, but i guess i still too new to this programming as i encounter an error and cannot understand the code.

Comment: how often video_NewFrame is called. mean frame rate per minute? I think there is no loop required. do not use writer.Close(); in this function as it will be called many times So you need to close it when you think your clip is complete. e.g make button stop and onclick call writer.Close();

Comment: there are only two lines required in video_NewFrame(), Bitmap image = eventArgs.Frame; and writer.AddFrame(image); and you have to change AVIWriter writer = new AVIWriter("MSVC"); to AVIWriter writer; and add  this line writer = new AVIWriter("MSVC");  before writer.Open("c:\\video.avi", 640, 480);

Comment: i tried removing the loop and added close button with this function `writer.Close();` but it throw an error and the video file created also corrupted(cannot be played)

Comment: update your post to reflect changes you made and also error thrown.

Comment: maybe i can save the frames first in folder and do the  scanning to the folder for image file and do the looping to create an avi file. how can i do this?

Comment: if your code currently posted is giving any error or not creating avi.

Comment: i tried your method from above using `using System.IO;` first, i download and save image file from camera snapshot and using your code to scan the folder to  add to `writer.AddFrame(img);` but what does `file` mean in this line `foreach file in filePaths`? i got error in here.

Comment: I am more interested in what error is returned from your current code as it exclude saving images to folder which is better way of doing this.

Comment: Please take a look to this code, i update my code here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12775225/how-can-i-improve-the-performance-of-code

Comment: I want to read the log file from this code, how can i create a log file(.txt) from this operation(time started, time end, etc)?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem currently, the answer is in the example you shared

```
AVIWriter writer = new AVIWriter( "wmv3" );
 writer.Open("video.avi", 640, 480);
```

and then use te jpegstream source